# Why can't this entry be added because of Foreign Key error?

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error when trying to add an entry to one of my tables.

```
'(`coursework1`.`ROUTE`,
   CONSTRAINT `FK_ROUTE_DELIVERY`
   FOREIGN KEY (`DELIVERY_VEHICLE_VEH_ID`)
   REFERENCES `DELIVERY` (`VEHICLE_VEH_ID`))'
```

Trying to add this code: `INSERT INTO ROUTE VALUES ('7418','66','200','313');`
into this table:

```
CREATE TABLE ROUTE (
 ROUTE_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 ROUTE_NAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 DELIVERY_VEHICLE_VEH_ID INT NOT NULL,
 DELIVERY_DRIVER_DR_ID INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FK_ROUTE_DELIVERY FOREIGN KEY (DELIVERY_VEHICLE_VEH_ID)
     REFERENCES DELIVERY (VEHICLE_VEH_ID),
 FOREIGN KEY (DELIVERY_DRIVER_DR_ID) REFERENCES DELIVERY (DRIVER_DR_ID));
```

Gives the error:

```
CANNOT ADD OR UPDATE A CHILD ROW: A FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT FAILS:
(coursework1.ROUTE, CONSTRAINT FK_ROUTE_DELIVERY FOREIGN KEY
    (DELIVERY_VEHICLE_VEH_ID) REFERENCES DELIVERY (VEHICLE_VEH_ID))
```

Other related tables

```
CREATE TABLE DELIVERY (
VEHICLE_VEH_ID INT NOT NULL,
DRIVER_DR_ID INT NOT NULL,
DEL_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
DEL_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (VEHICLE_VEH_ID , DRIVER_DR_ID),
INDEX (DRIVER_DR_ID),
INDEX (VEHICLE_VEH_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICLE_HAS_DRIVER_VEHICLE FOREIGN KEY (VEHICLE_VEH_ID) REFERENCES VEHICLE (VEH_ID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICLE_HAS_DRIVER_DRIVER FOREIGN KEY (DRIVER_DR_ID) REFERENCES DRIVER (DR_ID));

CREATE TABLE DRIVER (
 DR_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 DR_TITLE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 DR_FNAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 DR_LNAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 DR_DOB DATETIME NOT NULL,
 DR_LICENCENO VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 DR_PHONE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 DR_EMAIL VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: CANNOT ADD OR UPDATE A CHILD ROW: A FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT FAILS: (`coursework1`.`ROUTE`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ROUTE_DELIVERY` FOREIGN KEY (`DELIVE        RY_VEHICLE_VEH_ID`) REFERENCES `DELIVERY` (`VEHICLE_VEH_ID`))

Answer (score 2):

When you try to insert this record:

```
INSERT INTO ROUTE VALUES ('7418','66','200','313');
```

You are assuming that there is a value in `DELIVERY` with a `VEHICLE_VEH_ID` value of `'200'` and a `DELIVERY_DRIVER_DR_ID` value of `'313'`.  There error is telling you that there is no such record in that table.

A foreign key constraint means that the column(s) with that constraint is/are *constrained* to only point to valid records in the foreign table.  (In this case `DELIVERY`.)  Such a record must exist in that table before you can insert a dependent record in this table.

Comment: I tried to add an entry to the delivery table and the same error message comes up: this is the table - CREATE TABLE DELIVERY (
VEHICLE_VEH_ID INT NOT NULL,
DRIVER_DR_ID INT NOT NULL,
DEL_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
DEL_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (VEHICLE_VEH_ID , DRIVER_DR_ID),
INDEX (DRIVER_DR_ID),
INDEX (VEHICLE_VEH_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICLE_HAS_DRIVER_VEHICLE FOREIGN KEY (VEHICLE_VEH_ID) REFERENCES VEHICLE (VEH_ID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICLE_HAS_DRIVER_DRIVER FOREIGN KEY (DRIVER_DR_ID) REFERENCES DRIVER (DR_ID));


INSERT INTO DELIVERY VALUES ('200','313','6/2/2016','1500'); (procs error

Comment: @spoofskay: It means the same thing.  You're assuming a record in another table exists, but it doesn't.  A dependency has to exist before the thing which depends upon it can exist.